# "Set foreign_key_checks= 0;" but only for one database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have an umbrella MySQL server with many databases. I'd like to disable foreign keys for all tables in only one database. However the usual command disables foreign keys for all databases.

Is there a way for it to work in the scope of only one database?
Also, I'd like it to work not per session. But for session-wise globally.

Comment: I mean you can drop foreign keys on this DB, and restore when you need it agin

Answer (score 0):

No. The variable applies to all foreign keys on the MySQL instance. There is no way to limit it to the scope of one schema.

The only solutions are the ones you already know:

- `set foreign_key_checks=0` as a session variable, only for sessions that will access the schema you have in mind.
- Drop foreign key constraints in the tables of the schema you have in mind.
- Host the schema in a separate MySQL instance.